# Android action bar title id returning null in findViewbyId

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have referred to a variety of questions mentioned online using:

```
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title","id","android")
```

This is returning the correct ID, but when I call `findViewById(titleId)` in MainActivity, it is returning null.

Why does it happen and how can I get the view?

Comment: This is super-hacky and should never be used. You're accessing private data, and this method is not supported on several devices, so your code could potentially fail to run on other devices.

Try and explain what you want to do, and we can help you do it in a better way.

Comment: I want to change the color of the title dynamically in the application. I use ActionBar and not Toolbar, so need a work-around for ActionBar only.

Comment: Then take a look at the setCustomView function of the ActionBar - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView(android.view.View) - You can create a TextView, set the color on that textview, and then set that view as the custom ActionBar view. That'll put your TextView with the correct color into the ActionBar.

Comment: Thanks for the above reference. Is there a way to dynamically change the textcolor in ActionBar. I know we can change it in themes, but couldn't find the dynamic change reference anywhere.

Comment: Use the setCustomView whenever you want to change the ActionBar Title textcolor. You'll have to create a new textview, set the text & set the color each time. There is no "setTitleColor" function or similar.